# p-code of an if and block

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I was checking the p-code of a script, and I noticed this in the p-code:

```
ofs013c:iffalse ofs0156
...
ofs0156:iffalse ofs020d
...
ofs020d:...
```

this is a basic structure for something like this:

```
if('checksomething' && 'checksomethingelse')
{'dosomething'}
'continue'
```

Since it is an AND operator, shouldn't jump address in the first line of the p-code `ofs013c:iffalse ofs0156` be `ofs013c:iffalse ofs020d` instead? Even though no "proper" checks are done in `ofs013c:iffalse ofs020d` (if jumped to there from the first check), I wasn't expecting a jump there.

Is this a fault of the tool that I am using? Or is this how it goes in AS? Or is this how short-circuit looks like in pretty much anything?

Sorry, I have a limited knowledge in AS in general, maybe this isn't even related to AS at all. Most of the time I have to write in p-code rather than AS itself, and when I noticed this wanted to ask why it is like so. Anyway, have a nice day!

Comment: Not sure if you are using the AS2 Compiler, but that is what is does... in such a simple example, yes you can jump directly to `ofs020d`, but it is 'easier' to code that style of multiple jumps in the compiler to maintain the left to right order of operations (i.e. C-style ordering rules) and let the runtime JIT'er optimize it to `ofs020d`...  ;-)

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. The stuff I'm "trying" to work on is AS3 as far as I can tell, but then again, I am new to AS in general.